# mockito UnfinishedStubbingException missing thenReturn or you are trying to stub a final method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng

I am trying to run the below unit test - TestDummy using `TestNG`, `Mockito` on `Java7`

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest({TestA.class, TestB.class, Result.class, C.class})
public class TestDummy {

    @Test
    public void testIt() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(TestB.class);
        Result r = mock(Result.class);
        r.res = 2;
        TestB tB = mock(TestB.class);
        doReturn(tB).when(TestB.class, "get");
        when(tB.doSome(any(C.class))).thenReturn(r);

        Result rA = TestA.run();

        Assert.assertEquals(2, rA.res);
    }
}
```

Below is the source code I am trying to run the above unit test for -

```
class TestA {

    public static Result run() {
        TestB tB=TestB.get();
        return tB.doSome(new C());
    }
}

class Result {
    int res;
}

class TestB {

    static final TestB INS = new TestB();
    public static TestB get() {
        return INS;
    }

    public Result doSome(C c) {

        Result r = new Result();
        r.res=1;
        return r;
    }
}

class C {

}
```

but fails with the below error -

```
Running TestDummy
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.268 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestDummy
testIt(TestDummy)  Time elapsed: 0.527 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
at TestDummy.testIt(TestDummy.java:25)
```

Looks to be a trivial issue but stuck up here for a while. Would appreciate any inputs to resolve this without modifying the source code (modifying the unit test - TestDummy should be fine). I saw many posts regarding similar/same issues, however those suggestions doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Junit you use `@RunWith` but with TestNG you would need to specify this in your test case:

```
@ObjectFactory public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
     return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory(); 
}
```

Remember to add this dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged with `junit4` but the supplied code (which is a very useful MCVE, thanks :) suggests that you are using testng, `TestDummy` includes this import

```
org.testng.annotations.Test
```

So, I'm not sure which you are using.

Anyway, your code looks solid, I ran it successfully by making one simple change; adding `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` to `TestDummy`.

This was verified using the following:

- JUnit 4.12
- Powermock 1.7
- Mockito 2.7.19.

Comment: Wrongly tagged as junit4 instead of testng, my bad !

Comment: No problem, I've just updated the question to swap tags and I see you already have a solution in the other answer :)